# iOS SDK- How to get segue identifiers of viewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is there a way to get all segue identifiers for VC ?

Or just to know has the VC segue with identifier?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not a property, it's just a connection nod in the interface builder xml. It has nothing to do with the actual vc class. It just defines the transition between view controllers if you are using interface builder. So, no you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do what you are looking for.

If you could tell us why you need this then may be some one can give you directions to an alternative.

Edited:

If you really want to do it this way than you can use **try/catch**, something like this should work:

```
@try
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"first" sender:self];

}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    if ([exception.name isEqualToString:@"NSInvalidArgumentException"])
    {
        NSLog(@"NSInvalidArgumentException");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"second" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: I want realize following: 
If  myViewController has segue with identifier , say @"first", then perform it, else, present another vc modally.

Comment: Actually now I'm doing just like you wrote :)

Comment: Hmmm, may be you can accept the answer if this method works for you :).

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no method or property that one can use to get all the `identifiers` of the various `segues` in a `storyboard`.

To get the `identifier` of a particular `segue`, you can use the following code in the `prepareForSegue` method in the implementation of your `UIViewController` :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  NSString *segueIdentifier = segue.identifier; //This object stores your segue's identifier
  NSLog(@"%@", segueIdentifier);
}
```